# scatter versus covariance

Tags: probability-distributions, covariance

I am a bit confused about the difference between a scatter matrix (I believe it is sometimes called a scatter matrix) and the covariance. Some distributions, such as elliptical distributions, may not have a covariance matrix but always have a "scatter" matrix.

Can the covariance and scatter matrix coincide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scatter matrix is a function of a sample set that *estimates* the covariance matrix. As you point out, there are distributions for which the covariance is undefined, but if you restrict yourself to some finite set of sample points, you can always mechanically form the scatter matrix based on that sample (just as you can always estimate the mean of a 1-variable distribution by taking the average of a sample).

Yes, the two matrices can by luck coincide (assuming the covariance is definable), and in fact, there is a form of the law of large numbers that says that under certain conditions (which I believe are a bit stronger that just the existence of the covariance matrix) the limit for large $n$ of the scatter matrix approaches the covariance matrix.

An interesting exercise is to find a distribution for which the covariance matrix exists but is not accurately estimated by the limit of scatter matrices.  As I said, I believe there are some, but I can't think of an example.

Comment: Something I am confused about is that I have seen papers on elliptical distributions that refer to the "unknown scatter matrix" or "shape matrix". But from what you seem to be saying the scatter is more like the sample covariance, in the sense that it is defined in terms of a sample estimator. Am I missing something?

Comment: When talking about the *shape* matrix of an elliptical distribution, you are talking about a matrix that could be used to compute the iso-probabilility-density subspaces. This can be used to calculate the cov matrix. It seems that your references use "scatter matrix" for this concept interchangeably with shape matrix. That is a different definition than appears, for instance, in Wikipedia, where the scatter matrix is characteristic of one sample in the ensemble of finite sequences of variates.